# How to embed external html page in sharepoint 2003

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I m new to this sharepoint and we are using 2003 version we want to have one external html page to be embedded in sharepoint 2003. (Simply bringing one external html page throught sharepoint)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SharePoint Designer, you can add a Page Viewer Web Part to the area of the page where you want to display the external content.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Page-Viewer-Web-Part-e364436c-0ec4-4819-acac-1982b3525531

Alternatively, if you're editing the HTML you *may* be able to get away with using

```
<iFrame src="<URL to external content>" />.
```